# Bloqueando o cache do WebView

Tags: android, webview

To elaborando um WebApp, e uso um o WebView para abri uma url especifica dentro do app! Só que o app está armazenando tudo em cache, então caso eu venha fazer alguma alteração no site, o app não "computa" essa atualização, pois ele reutiliza todas informações que está no cache!

Como bloquear esse cache? Que, creio eu, está sendo gerado pelo WebView.

A plataforma do WebApp é android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desabilitar o cache assim:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Coloco isso no oncreate??

Comment: Sim, pode ser no onCreate

Comment: Nesse caso ai Rafael Telles, ele vai ativar o cache para desativar tem que por o false.

Comment: Ah sim, digitei errado, corrigindo, obrigado pelo toque